# Scale master shape on drop

Tags: scale, visio, shapesheet

I need to know how to set a master shape to scale down by percentage, when it is dropped onto page.

If I have a page that is 600 mm x 300 mm that is scaled 1:1 and I have a master shape that is 14 inches x 36 inches (a chicken door), and I want to drop it onto the page it is Gigantic and I have to scale it down manually every time.

I have a **Prop.Scale** cell that is set to ask to enter the Percentage on drop and I have the **DropOnPageScale** cell in the **Miscellaneous** Section in ShapeSheet with `=Prop.Scale/100`. Not even sure that is the right place to put that. Either way It does not work.

I cannot change the Scale on page nor change metric to standard since all the other parts are the main focus. In this case the main parts are the electronics controls for an automatic chicken door.

Visio Pro 2021

Comment: Sad buy true, [ShapeSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shapesheet/info) related questions are banned here. Although ShapeSheet is mentioned in the last paragraph of the [description of the subsection related to the Visio tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visio/info)

Comment: If you use page scale, you can use anti-scale multiplier like `20mm/ThePage!PageScale*ThePage!DrawingScale`

Comment: @Surrogate My apologies I was unaware that shapesheet questions were banned. Should I take it down? Also I went att his a different way. Instead of OnDrop, I made it right click Shape menu Option where you can input the desired percentage to scale down to. On drop or later. I won't put as solution since i think it's a different thing. TY anyway.

Comment: No problem ! It is not my idea delete ShapeSheet related threads in StackOverflow…